# How to remove commas and dots of individual word in two dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry, I am a beginner in learning Python so, I was complicated while trying to remove commas and dots of individual word in two dimensional list.

For example, I have:

```
list = [ ['Hello.', 'My', 'World,'] ]
```

Desired list:

```
desired_list = [ ['Hello', 'My', 'World'] ]
```

Thanks for Help!

Comment: You should try something before asking for help. Have you looked at `strip` function for example?

Comment: Is it JUST commas & periods? Or can there be other punctuation marks in the elements? Are there more elements to make this actually a 2D list? Have you tried any code yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with my solution:

```
list = [['Hello.', 'My', 'World,']]

list_n = []
for l in list:
    n = []
    for e in l:
        e = e.replace('.', '')
        e = e.replace(',', '')
        n.append(e)
    list_n.append(n)

print(list_n)
```

Output:

```
[['Hello', 'My', 'World']]
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strip` to remove `.` and `,` (if you have other punctuation marks in your words, you can add them):

```
l = [ ['Hello.', 'My', 'World,'] ]
res = [[j.strip('.,') for j in i] for i in l]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[['Hello', 'My', 'World']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not what was asked, but If you have a list with just one pair of straight parentheses, then the code is actually much easier to understand and remember:

```
list = ['Hello.', 'My', 'World,']

list2 = []
for e in list:
    e = e.replace('.', '')
    e = e.replace(',', '')
    list2.append(e)

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'My', 'World']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. list is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html) in python, don't use it as a variable!
2. there's a few ways to do this. Using iteration:

   ```
   l = [['Hello.', 'My', 'World,']]
   desired_list = []
   for word in l[0] #first element of l is a list of strings
       if '.' in word:
           desired_list.append(word.replace('.',''))
       elif ',' in word:
           desired_list.append(word.replace(',',''))
       else: desired_list.append(word)
   print desired_list
   ```
3. using list comp

   ```
   desired_list = [word.replace('.','').replace(',', '')  for word in l[0]]
   ```
4. keep in mind strings are **immutable** in Python, meaning they cannot be changed. word.replace() returns a copy of the word string with the replacement